# Pandas dataframe max and min value

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
+-----+---+---+--+--+
|     | A | B |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 288 | 1 | 4 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 245 | 2 | 3 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 543 | 3 | 6 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 867 | 1 | 9 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 345 | 2 | 7 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 122 | 3 | 8 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 233 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 346 | 2 | 6 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 765 | 3 | 3 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
```

What I want to do is get the max and min values from column 'B' given by the the range from 1 to 3 in column 'A'

For example:

```
loop on A in range 1 to 3:
       get max and min values from column 'B'
       max = 6
       min = 3
loop on the next range of A from 1 to 3:
       get max and min values from column 'B'
       max = 9
       min = 7           
loop on the next range of A from 1 to 3:
       get max and min values from column 'B'
       max = 6
       min = 1
```

and add the min max values to a column like:

```
+-----+---+---+--+----+
|     | A | B |min|max|
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 288 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 245 | 2 | 3 |   |   |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 543 | 3 | 6 |   |   |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 867 | 1 | 9 | 7 | 9 |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 345 | 2 | 7 |   |   |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 122 | 3 | 8 |   |   |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 233 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 346 | 2 | 6 |   |   |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
| 765 | 3 | 3 |   |   |
+-----+---+---+--+----+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If dont need empty values:

```
g = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 3)
df['min'] = g.B.transform('min')
df['max'] = g.B.transform('max')
print (df)
     A  B  min  max
288  1  4    3    6
245  2  3    3    6
543  3  6    3    6
867  1  9    7    9
345  2  7    7    9
122  3  8    7    9
233  1  1    1    6
346  2  6    1    6
765  3  3    1    6
```

For emty values is possible add empty spaces, BUT then all values in columns `min` and `max` are converted to strings too:

```
g = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 3)
df['min'] = g.B.transform('min')
df['max'] = g.B.transform('max')
df.loc[df.A != 1, ['min','max']] = ''
print (df)
     A  B min max
288  1  4   3   6
245  2  3        
543  3  6        
867  1  9   7   9
345  2  7        
122  3  8        
233  1  1   1   6
346  2  6        
765  3  3
```

EDIT1:

```
df['range']='range' + pd.Series(np.arange(len(df.index))//3 + 1, index=df.index).astype(str) 
g = df.groupby('range')
df['min'] = g.B.transform('min')
df['max'] = g.B.transform('max')
print (df)
     A  B   range  min  max
288  1  4  range1    3    6
245  2  3  range1    3    6
543  3  6  range1    3    6
867  1  9  range2    7    9
345  2  7  range2    7    9
122  3  8  range2    7    9
233  1  1  range3    1    6
346  2  6  range3    1    6
765  3  3  range3    1    6
```

Another solution with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of boolean mask:

```
df['range'] = 'range' + (df.A == 1).cumsum().astype(str)
g = df.groupby('range')
df['min'] = g.B.transform('min')
df['max'] = g.B.transform('max')
print (df)
     A  B   range  min  max
288  1  4  range1    3    6
245  2  3  range1    3    6
543  3  6  range1    3    6
867  1  9  range2    7    9
345  2  7  range2    7    9
122  3  8  range2    7    9
233  1  1  range3    1    6
346  2  6  range3    1    6
765  3  3  range3    1    6
```

Comment: I don't need the spaces but I do need to distinguish between ranges on column 'A'.  How can I add another column maybe column 'Range' and put the value of the current range.  For the first range from 1 to 3 maybe Range 1, and for the next Range maybe Range 2?

Comment: Can you check my answer. I'm on my phone

Comment: `df['range'] = 'range' + (np.arange(len(df.index)) // 3).astype(str)` and then `g = df.groupby('range')` I am only on phone so unchecked.
`

Comment: I get this error: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')

Comment: So try `df['range'] = 'range' +  pd.Series(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 3)).astype(str)`

Comment: It added the new column 'range' but the rows are all NaN.

Comment: Super, glad can help you.

Answer (score 2):

General solution

```
g = df.groupby(df.groupby('A').cumcount())
df['min'] = g.B.transform('min')
df['max'] = g.B.transform('max')
print (df)
     A  B  min  max
288  1  4    3    6
245  2  3    3    6
543  3  6    3    6
867  1  9    7    9
345  2  7    7    9
122  3  8    7    9
233  1  1    1    6
346  2  6    1    6
765  3  3    1    6
```

Comment: This also works but I need to add another column to keep track of the range.  For example add column Range then for the first range on A from 1 to 3 add 'Range 1' to the Range column then for the next range on A add 'Range 2' to the Range column etc...